# deleting a row with duplicate title with two or more condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with duplicate title and I can query them just fine when trying to find.

**Here's the table and code**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmrt0.png)

TABLE NAME: `documents`

```
+---------- +--------+
| module_srl| title  |
+---------- +--------+
| 6225      | test21 |
| 6225      | test   |
| 6225      | test   |
| 6226      | test3  |
| 6226      | test5  |
| 6226      | test6  |
+-----------+--------+
```

**SQL QUERY:**

```
SELECT title
FROM `documents`
WHERE module_srl = 6225
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
ORDER BY `documents`.`title` DESC
```

THIS SHOWS RESULT OF 1 which has 1 duplicate found (I guess)

**Title**

`test`

How do I delete "only" the duplicate title that matches `module_srl = 6225` without deleting the original.

Comment: you don't have primary key or unique key on this table? If not, you need add one.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me error : DELETE 
FROM documents
WHERE module_srl='6225' and title not in ( SELECT min(title) as min_title
                    FROM documents WHERE module_srl='6225'
                   GROUP BY title );

Comment: what's the error and what did you exactly tried?

Comment: tried to run that query and i get this error, that's the best i came up with ='( You can't specify target table 'documents' for update in FROM clause

Comment: you want to keep one 6225, test; or delete both?

Comment: I would like to keep one.

Comment: Do you have a primary key column in this table?

Comment: yes its document_srl but module_srl is like category in my table so I would like to delete duplicates using category and title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: I added the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the column identifier to differentiate the duplicate column.

The below query can delete any duplicate, instead of limit to module_srl 6255. if you want to limit to 6255, you can edit to add the where clause.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bec4/1)

```
delete from documents
where document_srl in (
    select document_srl
    from (
        select module_srl, min(document_srl) as document_srl
        from documents
        group by module_srl, title
        having count(*) > 1
    ) t
```